# d3 - trouble creating labels for x axis

Tags: d3.js

Right now I am using D3 v4 to try and create a simple line chart that has labels for the x axis. I am unsure of how to generate the labels properly.

Here is my gist: https://gist.github.com/pebblexe/0fa48e4b10426ccf3d339b9e9060e727

Also how does one go about making a gist that works with https://bl.ocks.org?

Thank you for your time and patience in answering this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confused by what kind of scale you want on that x-axis.  Right now you are using a `scaleTime`, which makes no sense since your x values are **not** dates or times.  Your choices then are a `scaleLinear` (if all your values are [numeric and continuous](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scaleLinear) - which seems to be what you are trying to do in your parse function).  **But** I really think a `scaleOrdinal` is more fitting for your data (and in particular a [scalePoint](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale/blob/master/README.md#scalePoint)).

Full running code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart0"></div>
<script>
  var data = {
    "studyGuide": {
      "count": 20,
      "avgTime": "4 minutes and 32 seconds",
      "unitCount": [{
        "name": "welcome",
        "count": 3
      }, {
        "name": "1",
        "count": 10
      }, {
        "name": "2",
        "count": 5
      }, {
        "name": "3",
        "count": 12
      }, {
        "name": "4",
        "count": 15
      }, {
        "name": "5",
        "count": 2
      }, {
        "name": "6",
        "count": 7
      }]
    }
  };

  var dataParsed = data['studyGuide']['unitCount'];

  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {
      top: 20,
      right: 20,
      bottom: 30,
      left: 50
    },
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // set the ranges
  var x = d3.scalePoint().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);

  // define the line
  var valueline = d3.line()
    .x(function(d) {
      return x(d.name);
    })
    .y(function(d) {
      return y(d.count);
    });

  // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
  // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
  // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
  var svg = d3.select("#chart0").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
      "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");


  // format the data
  dataParsed.forEach(function(d) {
    d.count = +d.count;
  });

  console.log("dataParsed", dataParsed);

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(dataParsed.map(d => d.name));
  y.domain([0, d3.max(dataParsed, function(d) {
    return d.count;
  })]);

  // Add the valueline path.
  svg.append("path")
    .data([dataParsed])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", valueline)
    .style("fill", "none")
    .style("stroke", "steelblue")
    .style("stroke-width", "2px");

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(y));
</script>
```

---

To fix your blocks problem, you need the base html file to be named **index.html**, here's your code as a blocks gist: https://bl.ocks.org/larsenmtl/93cb0b5a5201d63e679826877406b606

Comment: Thank you! That was indeed my problem. Also thank you for explaining how bl.ocks.org works.

Comment: @pebblexe, if this solves your problem, remember to check the "checkmark" next to my answer.  That'll mark the question complete and improve the `d3.js` answer statistics.

Comment: Sorry, my bad I forgot.